# How do I stop Unity from remembering search history?

Tags: unity, 12.04, unity-dash, customization

Is it possible to stop Unity from remembering the past search history? If I search for "settings" and then close and reopen the unity dash, the word "settings" is still in the search bar. I want to do a NEW search, not an old one.

Answer (score 7):

It's actually designed that way. But if you want to do a new search, then you can just type. It's not configurable.

Press Esc to clear the search though. If there's a previous search, the first time you press Esc, you'll empty the input field. The next time you press Esc, you'll close the Dash.

Comment: Thanks! your answer also helped mine in [How to disable the activity log for the application lens?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194689/how-to-disable-the-activity-log-for-the-application-lens)

Answer (score 3):

In 12.04 there is a tool for privacy under system settings. I have mine set to off so it wont record activity with the desktop/Dash, along with many other applications. You can also clear recent history there.

Comment: Won't that also disable application and file ranking (i.e., when the Dash lists last-used apps and files first, and improves its partial matching)?