# Can I make the dash forget the previous search each time it opens?

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop Unity from remembering search history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124335/how-do-i-stop-unity-from-remembering-search-history)

I would like the search bar to be empty each time, just like how windows vista onwards lets you press Super, type a few letters, press enter, and subsequently your desired program/file will pop up (a few minutes later). The beauty is that you don't have to click or backspace to get rid of your previous search each time.
I'm on 12.04.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, because I don't mind my history being remembered. However, an answer for that is a sufficient answer for this: http://askubuntu.com/a/124344/41024. I can't post an answer to my own question for another 7 hours apparently.

Comment: I'm confident the questions "mean" the same thing.  The only point of contest is the wording of the question.  Just my opinion.

Comment: @LyndenShields The question is the same, and see this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/124344/4937).

Comment: Yep that's what I linked to - everyone's so fast though, thanks!