# How to disable the activity log for the application lens?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, zeitgeist, applications-lens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop Unity from remembering search history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124335/how-do-i-stop-unity-from-remembering-search-history)

How to clear search history of application search? Every time when I select application lens or press Super+A it shows up the last search and narrows down my applications based on my last search. I just want a clear application search with all the installed applications.
This screenshot shows my previous search "cal"
[image]

I want like this (below screenshot) every time I press Super+A
[image]

..

Comment: Do you want to clear your search history our completely disable the feature for applications/any type of entries in the dash?

Comment: @Glutanimate I don't want to completely disable the feature but want a clear search application just like when we search for the first time without clearing any history manually.

Comment: but you want that cleared search to be permanent, right?  you want the search to stop recording any recent applications and only show what's installed on your system, regardless of whether you used it or not.

Comment: @Glutanimate I want to use search application only when I need to use otherwise it should be clear of any search of the previous search items and shows all the installed application

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. I can't think of any easy solution right now, but I'll get back to you if I find one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I keep recent files from appearing in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29559/how-can-i-keep-recent-files-from-appearing-in-unity) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/28977/how-to-hide-recent-files-and-most-used-apps

Comment: @Takkat I don't think this is duplicate as I am talking about clearing the Search Application of APPLICATION LENS when we press Super+A not a particular app or some erotic folder. I tried your link but it doesn't full fill my question. I would like to request you to look in the screenshot I have just uploaded, I want that clear every time I press Super+A. Also I deeply request you to re consider the question and vote to re open the same.

Comment: @Glutanimate My question is now closed, do you think this question is duplicate of those links. It appears to me by your last comment, you have understand my question, I would like to request you also to vote to re open the question enabling the question to be answered by the member of the Askubuntu.

Comment: @Namshum: if you do follow the answers from the duplicate questions to open *"Privacy"* settings you will very easily find a *"Delete History"* button. This is from one of the answers: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O2fss.png.

Comment: @Takkat I have turned off the Record Activity from the "Privacy" already. I want to clarify once again that when I press Super+A for the 1st Time and then type suppose "Cal" to search calculator and again when I press Super+A for the 2nd Time it shows the previous search "Cal", I want this "Cal" to cleared after I select the app calculator or when dash has lost focus.

Comment: If your actual question is to clear the dash search, do be told that it is by design. See also: [How do I stop Unity from remembering search history?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124335/how-do-i-stop-unity-from-remembering-search-history)

Comment: @jokerdino Great! Hats off to you. I have no word to Thank you. So, by its design doesn't let us to clear its history. We have to press **"ESC"** if we have to clear up the history. I would like to request you to closed my question on basis of the link you have provided not on the earlier links for the greater community interest.

Comment: Alright. I'll flag the question to be closed on the right dupe target. No worries.